# Revisionable presenters not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, revisionable

First I find a ticket.

```
$tick = App\Tickets::find(14);
```

Then I find a revision for the same:

```
$rev = $tick->latestRevision;
```

But it gives me a error:

```
App\Presenters\Revisions\Tickets #0000000021ba4aef0000000179e23051 {}
```

When I see in database, the revisions table is updated with a revision.

And this is my Presenters code:

```
namespace App\Presenters\Revisions;

use Sofa\Revisionable\Laravel\Presenter;

class Tickets extends Presenter {

protected $passThrough = [
        'stage_id'        => 'stage.stage_name',

    ];
protected $actions = [
        'created'  => 'Created at',
        'updated'  => 'Updated at',
        'deleted'  => 'Deleted',
        'restored' => 'Restored',
    ];
}
```

So this is my relation from Tickets model.

```
public function stage() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Stages');
    }
```

And I used stage.stage_name in passThrough, but still there is no result.

Also, when I do `$revision->old('stage_id');` , I get `null`

I am using this package: https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/revisionable

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, that is the `tinker` output showing you your `App\Presenters\Revisions\Tickets` object.

Do a `$rev->getDiff()` and it should work fine.

Comment: I am getting `null` when I output this: `$revision->old('stage_id');
=> null`

Comment: @phantomphoenix I would assume that would be the case if your stage has never changed from the first time it was set, or if the stage related to the old stage_id isn't found.